# Make programmatic Simulink changes undoable

Tags: simulink, undo

Is it possible to make programmatically introduced changes to Simulink blocks undoable? So that a user may hit `Ctrl+Z` or the corresponding menu/toolbar entry to restore the previous state.

Comment: Why would you need this ? Did you enter a flight with your co-worker or a mentee ?

Comment: If I want to extend Simulink's context menu by a cool new feature, like "Delete all lines in current Subsystem" then maybe the user wants to undo it, just like the "Create Subsystem from Selection" is undoable by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I finally got an official answer from Mathworks. Unfortunately it's not very satisfying. They say:

```
there isn't an API for the undo button
```